# Layout is not including in the main file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've the main file which is `welcome.blade.php` where I've  mark up something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            @yield('title')    // title from signup.blade.php
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- some content here -->


         @yield('signup')    // I'm loading this from signup.blade.php



        <!-- some content here -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm loading sign up `page` from `signup.blade.php` which is in directory `layouts/signup.blade.php`.

`signup.blade.php` page has code something like this:

```
@include('welcome')

@section('title')

    measurement

@endsection

@section('signup')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

The structure of the files is like this :

`resources/views/welcome.blade.php`

`resources/views/layouts/signup.blade.php`

But the **problem** is neither the `title` is showing when I load `welcome.blade.php` neither the `sign up form` appears.

**Note:** The title is showing `localhost:8000` , don't know why ?

Am I doing anything wrong, please help me thanks.

Comment: `welcome.blade.php` this is the master template. right?

Comment: Yeah, that is right ! @zahidhasanemon

Comment: now you want to load the signup page with this template?

Comment: Yess, @zahidhasanemon

Comment: How do you load `signup.blade.php` from `Controller`?

Comment: @ZeshanKhattak ,I haven't created Controller yet, I've done this in `web.php` something like this :

`Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
}); `

Comment: you need to return view `layouts.signup`. not the master template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your master template *welcome.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            @yield('title')
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
         @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

And now any page that will use this template need to extends it. In your case *signup.blade.php*

```
@extends('welcome')

@section('title')

    measurement

@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: This is what I've already, @zahid hasan emon, you've just change the name to `content`, but I tried, still this is not working

Comment: Okay, the title is working but the `signup` form is still not loading